# What is the exact word used for this unusual "interval" of sorts?

Tags: word-choice

I knew this word a long time ago. Then I lost my memory. childhood and all. mva trauma, head injury.. I was good with words before because I was a songwriter, and I had a feeling that this word was etched in my memory somewhere but was just inaccessible.. knowing this word again could solve a lot of consequent problems in writing/overcome writers block to some degree for me.

So here it is: You know how there is an "interval" between say a "train of events"? "Interval" is the best and only word I could think of -closest to this phenomenon- to describe it.

To be a bit more vivid, imagine a train (locomotive) with 10 carriages, and the third and fourth carriage missing above the wheels. So, as the train moves past you, there is a "gap" that transitions through your visual and sound spectrum yes? What is this phenomenon? "Something" (that) passes by you.. It is a very obvious word, but I just can't figure out.. Even after one of you points it out, I might have to give it a memory marker to make it a long term memory- as my short term memory is still not in very good shape (or maybe it's just in the head).

Further, imagine this "gap" or "interval" of sorts streaking past you like a bullet.. What is this phenomenon? :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a clear understanding of the phenomenon you are attempting to describe, but imagine at least the first of the following is relevant:

• *[caesura](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caesura#Noun)*, “A pause or interruption in a poem, music, building or other work of art”  (Also see [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesura))
• *[lapse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lapse#Noun)*, “A pause in continuity”, “An interval of time between events”
• *[interruption](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interruption#Noun)*, “A time interval during which there is a [cessation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cessation#Noun) of something”

Comment: Try also [hiatus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hiatus).

Answer (score 1):

**Break...like, "break in the action?"** A void that streaks past? This is a cool thing to contemplate. The valley of a light wave? Cosmic ray antiparticles? The resume of Danica Patrick? You mentioned sound. Are you looking for a staccato effect? I just looked at Thesaurus.com, and there seem to be many synonyms for interval. Have you looked at those? Is it akin to punctuation? How about pulsate? Beat, throb, vibration?

Answer (score 1):

'hiatus' is a break, pause or interruption in a sequence, series or process. 
e.g.: 'The show was on hiatus for three months and was not expected to start up again until April.

'After a 23-year hiatus he only made one more appearance at a major golf tournament before retiring.'

Answer (score 1):

Since you composed, an interlude is apropos:

> **[INTERLUDE](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interlude)** : an intervening or interruptive period, space, or event :
>   interval 3 : a musical composition inserted between the parts of a
>   longer composition...

Answer (score 1):

"Window" captures some of the meaning you're trying to express; in the sense of a gap between solid things, as well as something moving and only available for a certain period of time, as a "launch window."

Answer (score 0):

May be you are referring to a form of:

> [numbness or blankness of mind](http://psychcentral.com/ask-the-therapist/2010/05/06/numbnessblankness-of-mind-ptsd/).